# If $f(x)$ is maximised, then when $x=1/2$ when is $g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}f(x)$ maximised?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ that has a strict global maximum $x=1/2$ and $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow0, \infty^+$. Define $g(x)$ as follows:

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}f(x)$$

Does $g(x)$ have a maximum at $x=0.5$?

---

Hint: Given that $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow0, \infty^+$, $g(x)$ will have a maximum when $0<x<1$. Moreover,
$$\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=f'(x)\frac{1}{1-x}+f(x)\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Hence, 
$$g'(x)=0 \iff f'(x)\frac{1}{1-x}=-f(x)\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \iff \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-\frac{1}{(1-x)}$$

We also know that $f'(x)=0 \iff x=1/2$.

I think this question cannot be answered since $f(0.4)$ may be $0.5-\epsilon$ and $g(0.4)$ may therefore be bigger than $g(0.5)$, it depends on $f'(x)$, which we do not know. Is this correct?

Comment: there seem to be a mistake in your derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the nice continuous function $$f(x)=\dfrac{2x}{4x^2+1},$$ which satisfies all your given conditions. However $g(x)=-\dfrac{f(x)}{x-1}$ has no global maximum in $(0,1)$.